# Base converter that return string

Tags: c, string, recursion, type-conversion

I have a problem i need to convert the number received from converting into a string and then return it.The problem is i don't know how I tried to add use (char)(number + 48) but it not works i tried with itoa function but same thing.But the function need to be recursive.
Thanks for help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int itoc (int number, int base) {

    if(number == 0) return number;

    return (number % base) + 10 * itoc(number / base, base);
}


int main()
{   int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d", &number ,&base);
    printf("%d",itoc(number,base));
    return 0;
}
```

The version above is the version which return an integer.

Comment: Is the recursive call mandatory ?

Comment: Your program works, as long as the conversion doesn't overflow and the base is not greater than 10. For which input values did you find it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways. One of my way to use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Here you need a little change for this like the following way:

```
int main()
{
    int number,base;
    scanf("%d %d", &number ,&base);
    int ret=itoc(number,base);
    char str[32];
    sprintf(str, "%d", ret);//this convert it to string.
   // printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```